# Last Row of Filtered DataView in C#

Tags: c#, dataview

I have a DataView which was filtered to contain only those records I need. On top of that I would like to get the first record in the Dataview.

```
    //appDV contains a bunch of records with different LOAN_STATUS. Here I'm filtering it by Approved

        appDV.RowFilter = "LOAN_STATUS = 'Approved'";
        appDV.Sort = "CREATE_TIME DESC";
        // If more than one record, take the 1st record
        appuser = new AppUserVO();
        appuser.APPUSER_ID = Convert.ToInt32(appDV.Table.Rows[0]["APPUSER_ID"].ToString());
        appuser.BankLenderId = appDV.Table.Rows[0]["BANK_LENDERID"].ToString().Trim();
        AppList.Add(appuser);


        return AppList;
```

The code above is not returning the correct Row... because it is returning me the Row of the DataView BEFORE the filter was applied.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't get the row from the data table.  You have to get it from the data view (dataview[row idx]).

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the .Table. call and instead should use

```
appDV.Rows[0]["APPUSER_ID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set sort expression and row filter, you have to call DataView.ToTable()

Answer (score -1):

To get a column value from the first row :

```
string columnVal= appDV.ToTable().Rows[0]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
```

You must use the `.ToTable()` first to convert you retrieved values in the DataView to a DataTable.